What is the default behavior of the Raspberry Pi OS when both adapters are connected to the same network?
What is the default behavior of the Raspberry Pi OS when both adapters (wired and wireless) are connected to the same network?
In Windows, there is a setting, which is usually automatic, where the OS will prefer the wired network adapter over the wireless one, if it detects they are on the same network.  I believe it will also turn off the radio, but I'm not 100% sure on that one.
I'm setting up some Octoprint instances, and and contemplating if setting them up on Wifi as a backup will cause problems.  I want them to use/prefer the wired connection, but it would be nice if I have to remove the cable for some reason, that I can still access them via wifi.
This question is similar, but not a duplicate of what I'm asking.

Most of my Pi have both Ethernet & WiFi connection to my router. Everything works. If you have a problem you should explain.

You can check the default behaviour with route

It depends on the metric value of each link, plus you can only have one default route from your Pi to the outside world. The ip route show command shows the details.
